# Openpyxl append doesn't add data at the end of row

Tags: python, append, openpyxl

I'm trying to get a row from a Workbook and append it at the end of another Workbook.

```
rowLst = []
rowLst = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=8, max_row=8, min_col=3, max_col=ws1.max_column,values_only=True)

#append list to excel
ws2.append(myList)
```

But instead of adding the row right after the data from "Bus" it goes way beyond.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and will post it here in case anyone will have the same problem. 
Although the cells below looked empty, they had apparently, weird formatting.
That's why the Python script saw the cells as Non-empty and appended the data in another place(the place where there was no formatting).

The Solution would be to format every row below your data as empty cells. (Just copy a range of empty cells from a new Workbook and paste it below your data)

Hope that helps! ;)